# How to change pagename in dokuwiki?

Tags: dokuwiki

everybody

I made a wiki system using dokuwiki-stable, but fail to change pagename which created recently.

Is it possible to change pagename? Here's offical detail: [pagename](https://www.dokuwiki.org/pagename)

Any effort will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single page just copy the content to the new page and delete the old.

See https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq:howto-rename-pages